# How to create root element of my input xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to create the root element of which is not available template in the input

XML I used as:

```
<Body>
<p outputclass="Body_Text">AAAA.</p>

<p outputclass="Normal"><b>Q:</b> Why?</p>
<p outputclass="Body_Text_Question"><b>Q:</b> What?</p>
<p outputclass="Body_Text_Answer"><b>A:</b> In.</p>
<p outputclass="Body_Text_Answer">The</p>

<p outputclass="Normal"><b>Q:</b> Why?</p>
<p outputclass="Body_Text_Question"><b>Q:</b> What?</p>
<p outputclass="Body_Text_Answer"><b>A:</b> In.</p>
<p outputclass="Body_Text_Answer">The</p>
</Body>
```

XSL I used:

```
<xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Body_Text']">
    <para>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </para>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Normal']">
    <item num="{replace(node()[1], '^\s+', '')}">
      <para><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[position() gt 1]"/></para>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Body_Text_Question'][b]">
    <item num="{replace(node()[1], '^\s+', '')}">
      <para><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[position() gt 1]"/></para>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Body_Text_Answer'][b]" priority="10">
    <item num="{replace(node()[1], '^\s+', '')}">
      <para><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[position() gt 1]"/></para>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Body_Text_Answer']">
      <para><xsl:apply-templates/></para>
     </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Output I'm getting like:

```
<Body>

   <para>AAAA.</para>


   <item num="Q:">
      <para> Why?</para>
   </item>

   <item num="Q:">
      <para> What?</para>
   </item>

   <item num="A:">
      <para> In.</para>
   </item>

   <para>The</para>


   <item num="Q:">
      <para> Why?</para>
   </item>

   <item num="Q:">
      <para> What?</para>
   </item>

   <item num="A:">
      <para> In.</para>
   </item>

   <para>The</para>

</Body>
```

Expected output would be(needs to close the item list after the normal para and orderlist on the end of the all question and answer types):

```
<Body>

   <para>AAAA.</para>

   <orderedlist type="manual">
   <item num="Q:">
      <para> Why?</para>
   </item>

   <item num="Q:">
      <para> What?</para>
   </item>

   <item num="A:">
      <para> In.</para>


   <para>The</para></item>


   <item num="Q:">
      <para> Why?</para>
   </item>

   <item num="Q:">
      <para> What?</para>
   </item>

   <item num="A:">
      <para> In.</para>


   <para>The</para></item>
   </orderedlist>

</Body>
```

I need to create root element (order list) for the question and answers types. I'm using XSLT version 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is similar to the following article:

[How to get the normal paras with different outpuclass as a section level tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45611291/how-to-get-the-normal-paras-with-different-outpuclass-as-a-section-level-tags/45650712#45650712)

But the list generation requirement is bit different. You can use xsl:for-each-group/@group-adjacent to solve this question. I added "Body" template for controlling grouping. Another templates are not changed from original.

[Sample stylesheet]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="Body">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::p[@outputclass='Body_Text'])">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <orderedlist type="manual">
                            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::p[string(@outputclass) = ('Normal','Body_Text_Question')])">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <item>
                                            <xsl:attribute name="num" select="replace(current-group()[1]/b[1], '^\s+', '')"/>
                                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                                        </item>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:for-each-group>
                        </orderedlist>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Body_Text']">
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Normal']">
        <item num="{replace(node()[1], '^\s+', '')}">
            <para><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[position() gt 1]"/></para>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Body_Text_Question'][b]">
        <item num="{replace(node()[1], '^\s+', '')}">
            <para><xsl:apply-templates select="node()[position() gt 1]"/></para>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Body_Text_Answer'][b]" priority="10">
        <para><xsl:apply-templates select="node() except b[position() eq 1]"/></para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@outputclass='Body_Text_Answer']">
        <para><xsl:apply-templates/></para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

[The result]

```
<Body>
    <para>AAAA.</para>
    <orderedlist type="manual">
        <item num="Q:">
            <para> Why?</para>
        </item>
        <item num="Q:">
            <para> What?</para>
        </item>
        <item num="A:">
            <para> In.</para>
            <para>The</para>
        </item>
        <item num="Q:">
            <para> Why?</para>
        </item>
        <item num="Q:">
            <para> What?</para>
        </item>
        <item num="A:">
            <para> In.</para>
            <para>The</para>
        </item>
    </orderedlist>
</Body>
```